# One variable with three colors, but only one color on the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend, na

I have two variables in my table. I want one of them to appear with three colors on the graph, but only one color on the legend. How can I remove the NAs, which don't correspond to separate variables, from the legend?

My code below allows me to have the three colors (black, red and green) on the graph as well as the blue of the second variable. I want the black and blue colors only on the legend. Could you please help me?

Here are some observations of my database and my R script:

```r
structure(list(Company = c("Ryanair", "Ryanair", "Ryanair", "Ryanair", 
"Ryanair", "Ryanair", "Ryanair", "Ryanair", "Ryanair", "Ryanair", 
"Singapore Airlines", "Singapore Airlines", "Singapore Airlines", 
"Singapore Airlines", "Singapore Airlines", "Singapore Airlines", 
"Singapore Airlines", "Singapore Airlines", "Singapore Airlines", 
"Singapore Airlines"), Year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), tei_tl = c(0.79265, 0.8301, 0.90591, 
0.89794, 0.92407, 0.91998, 1, 0.91571, 0.80457, 0.69001, 0.80559, 
0.80162, 0.79714, 0.76219, 0.75193, 0.81753, 0.83193, 0.79027, 
0.28713, 0.6495), EU = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Ann_av_te = c(0.77291, 0.80389, 0.83033, 
0.81141, 0.79951, 0.8164, 0.83807, 0.81942, 0.56056, 0.66667, 
0.77291, 0.80389, 0.83033, 0.81141, 0.79951, 0.8164, 0.83807, 
0.81942, 0.56056, 0.66667)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```r
ggplot(data = datateff) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = tei_tl, group=Company, color=(ifelse((EU == 1), "green", 'black')))) + 
  labs(x="Year", y="") + 
  geom_point(size=1, aes(x = Year, y = tei_tl, size=.7, group=Company, color=tei_tl <1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = Ann_av_te, group=Company, color=('#33CCFF'))) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c( '#33CCFF',"black", "red", "green", "black"), 
                     name="", labels=c("TEI annual averages", "TEI")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Company, nrow=5, ncol=4) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=6), axis.title=element_text(size=8), 
        text=element_text(size=8), 
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 6), 
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=6), 
        legend.position = c(1.0, .01), 
        legend.justification = c("right", "bottom"), 
        legend.box.just = "right", 
        legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6))
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. Also, please do not add data as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121) This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. In your case, that means providing enough data so there are at least two Company values and some of those with EU == 1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only some categories in the legend you could do so via the `breaks=` argument of `scale_color_manual` which however requires to use a named vector of colors.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `ggplot2::mpg`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = setNames(
      scales::pal_brewer(type = "qual")(7),
      unique(mpg$class)
    ),
    breaks = c("compact", "midsize"),
    labels = c(compact = "Compact", midsize = "Midsize")
  )
```

[image]

**UPDATE** And based on your real data it's just a matter of properly naming categories:

```
ggplot(data = datateff) +
  geom_line(aes(
    x = Year, y = tei_tl, group = Company,
    color = ifelse(EU == 1, "non_tei", "tei")
  )) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "") +
  geom_point(size = 1, aes(
    x = Year, y = tei_tl, size = .7, group = Company,
    color = tei_tl < 1
  )) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = Ann_av_te, group = Company, color = "ann_av_te")) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(
      ann_av_te = "#33CCFF", tei = "black", "FALSE" = "red",
      non_tei = "green", "TRUE" = "black"
    ),
    name = NULL,
    breaks = c("ann_av_te", "tei"),
    labels = c(ann_av_te = "TEI annual averages", tei = "TEI")
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~Company, nrow = 5, ncol = 4) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(size = 6), axis.title = element_text(size = 8),
    text = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 6),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "black", size = 6),
    legend.position = c(1.0, .01),
    legend.justification = c("right", "bottom"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: The "breaks" statement removes the colors and the legend. The problem is that my variable takes on three colors depending on the conditions defined in "geom".

Comment: Well, of course do you have to use the right names and overall I would suggest to use better labels than color codes or names. See my update.